# C++ .length() stops counting number of letters when spaces appear

Tags: c++

I have a while loop in this program. I want it so that it runs the program for as many letters as there are in the user input. This works when there are no spaces in the user input, but when there are it stops counting the number of letters as soon as the space appears. Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> cons = {"b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q",    "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y"};
vector<string> vowel = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
int count_val = 0;
string user_translate;

int main(){
    cout << "Enter the word you want translated: ";
    cin >> user_translate;
    while(count_val < user_translate.length()){
        if(user_translate[count_val] == ' '){
            cout << "No sentences!";
        }
        cout << user_translate.length();
        ++count_val;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why the .length() is not working properly. Am I doing something wrong is there a another method I could use to find the number of letters with the spaces added. Thanks.

Comment: How are you populating `user_translate` ? `cin >> user_translate` will stop reading at the first whitespace for example. Possibly use `std::getline()` instead.

Comment: Check what `user_translate` contains and what `user_translate.length()` returns.

Comment: I have a cin statement to let the user enter their input

Comment: I have tried cout statements on the .length() and I have found that it counts up to the space

Comment: Can you show us the code where you put user input in `user_translate`? Because the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) for `std::string::length` do not say that a space will signal the end of the string's "length."

Comment: @user3262301 You have much more likely found out that your string only extends to the first space in the user's input.

Comment: @user3262301 like `cin >> user_translate`? The extraction operator `>>` uses whitespace as delimiters.

Comment: easy to debug: just `cout << user_translate` and see what is going on. else if the input is too long to test that way, count how many spaces you have in the input and count how often you hit the 'no sencences!' output.

Comment: I have added the full code

Comment: This is a failure to narrow down your problem, which has *nothing to do with `.length()`*. Please debug your code more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string str;
std::getline(cin,str);
int len = str.length();
```

This way you can get the actual length of sting having white space too.

`std::cin>> str`; //  It will not read the read string as soon as the first white space appears in the string.

Like if you want to enter a string `My name is Mama` using `std::cin>>str;` only  `str = "My"` will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are either not reading in the spaces or you accidentally trim them off.
The first case is much more likely.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

operator>>(std::istream, std::string)   reads characters into the string, **skipping leading whitespace**,

> until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> - N characters are read, where N is stream.width() if stream.width() > 0,    otherwise N is string.max_size()
> - the end-of-file condition occurs in the stream
> - **std::isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the next character c in the stream**.

Therefore, stream >> string doesn't ever put whitespace into the string.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` skips all `whitespace (spaces, tabs, new lines, etc.)` by default.
You can either change its behavior by using `nowskips` .

I'd suggest using `get` :

> cin.get( user_translate, n );

get will stop retrieving chars from the stream if it either finds a `newline char (\n) or after n-1 chars`.
Now, you can use `user_translate.length` .

Comment: `noskipws` does not do what you think it does.